# how to push correct time from input textbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

i want to push time in my database but when i push time my $scope.moreadditems variable its save wrong time please help me i am using angularjs 
 check when i enter time 9:00 AM why this show different time

[check jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7322/)
`i am adding below time its working fine add in table`[image]

but when i click show details its show different time
and also this time in database why
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`input[time]` will always output datetime of `1970-01-01` + the time you inputed, see documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D).

If you just want to keep the `time` part, you can use filter `date` to pick it, and don't forget to inject `$filter` first.

```
var timeHHMM = $filter('date')(time, 'hh:mm');
```

refer [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/marrypen/gsn6q5ou/1/).